# How to make whatsapp button menu

Tags: menu, whatsapp

How to make whatsapp button menu just like this

[image]

Does anyone have tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a layout file looking like this.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This user does not exist in your contacts."
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Block"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Block"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Block"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can customise it with the images and the text you want.It is just a sample one.

**NOTE :** This ui is made in linearLayout with vertical orientation.